# How to add external css file in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I have a css file called test.css.
I want to show the css classes defined in test.css inside the ckeditor style dropdown.
I added the plug in stylesheetparser.But css classes are not showing in the editor

Below is my code in the config.js

```
config.extraPlugins = 'stylesheetparser';
config.contentsCss = 'test.css';
```

Can somebody help me on this..